# map different objects to a mongoose db model with common object(db) model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Can we guys implement a common DB model while the responses from different data sources have some differences?

Example,

My DB schema is as under:

```
//Common database schema
var CoreSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    "TransectionDate":String,
    "ValueDate":String,
    "Description":String,
    "ReferenceNo":String,
    "DebitAmount":Number,
    "CreditAmount":Number,
    "BalanceAmount":Number,
});
```

While my INPUT data sources (3rd party which I do not have control over) have different column names for the same set of data. like some APIs which provide me data provided as (schema is not provided for brevity).

```
Txn Date
Value Date
Description
Ref No./Cheque No.
Debit
Credit
Balance
```

While other sources have

```
Date
Narration
Chq.Ref.No.
Value Dt
Withdrawal Amt.
Deposit Amt.
Closing Balance
```

Now my concern is how we should map (like auto-mapper or something that sort of) these data to the core model. Note that even sometimes the order of columns is different, however if there is a way in JS or NodeJs to provide ***data annotation*** like in other languages like c#, I would love to implement.

(I've thought of iterating the data while insert/update, if nothing works. However I feel this is not a idea what I would like to go for.)

Please suggest, your thoughts on this.

BTW, I've checked few SO posts already so please do not refer other threads unless you are sure enough to suggest the exact solution.

Thanks.

N Baua

Comment: Even if you write a class which builds you the `Schema` for you, the order in which you send the field names to the class constructor is a problem you have to tackle by looking at each of source documents. You are better off building Schema's as you go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with updating the source JSON keys (column headers) which now map to the schema properly.

I know this is a hack, however posting it here as someone would find it easy and helpful.

--N Baua